# Our Jacuzzi tub just stopped draining. What could be causing this? We’ve tried it all

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathroom-fixtures

We’ve just moved into an older home which happens to have a Jacuzzi tub.  I’m sure it hasn’t been used in years, but it fired up just fine and we’ve used it 4 times.  However, all of a sudden it just wouldn’t drain.  We tore apart the handle and pop drain mechanism, but this seems to be working just fine.  We’ve put Drayno down the drain, but nothing seems to be happening... not even a trickle of water sound to suggest it’s clogged with some organic material.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Be careful now that you've put Drano down it which hasn't drained away, and make sure you inform anyone else who works on it that you've done so. It can cause serious chemical burns.

Comment: please don't say `We’ve tried it all` ... if it's plugged, then you have not "tried it all" ... the draining problem may be the reason why it has not been used in years

Comment: Frozen drain line perhaps.  What is th temperature outside?

Comment: How about snaking the drain line? A small hand-operated one can be picked up for around $20 or so, or you could rent a larger powered auger.

Comment: If you got the right Drano (I don't know that specific product line) - ie one that will eventually fall to the lowest point no matter what's in the way, then you could leave it up to a week to see if it eventually gets through, before trying to rod it or even plunge it. If you've got a jacuzzi full of water you have a good head to keep it pushing through, if the drano starts to work. It wouldn't surprise me if it took 3 or 4 litres of product to fully clear it. I recently had a stubborn sink it wasn't possible to rod because of a nasty pipe routing, so this is all still fresh in my mind ;)